# Main AppDelegate not getting called in universal application for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios-universal-app

I am working on xcode project intended to make a universal app.With the window based application template i got 3 AppDelegate Methods.2 for both ipad and iphone each and 1 Main AppDelegate method.When i run it for ipad ,the Main AppDelegate method is being called but when i run it for iphone environment ,the Main AppDelegate is not getting called.So how to get the controller to Main Appdelegate method while running it for Iphone environment..??

Here is description..
I have 3 appdelegate methods ,viz.prjOUMAppDelegate(main appdelegate),prjOUMAppDelegate_iPhone(for iphone),prjOUMAppDelegate_iPad(for ipad)..
I have some common methods like creating folders and moving files written in prjOUMAppDelegate(main appdelegate)method.I want it to run everytime irrespective of device ,so that i can get my folders created and some files to be moved.Its working fine when i run it for ipad(i.e creating folders and moving files ) but when i change the environment to iphone ,the prjOUMAppDelegate(main appdelegate) method is not getting called..so i dont know where iam getting wrong..

Comment: I think you need to explain a bit more with code as this is really getting confusing.

Comment: @ParthBhatt:see my edited question

Comment: It's not common to have more than one AppDelegate as there is hardly ever reason to do so. Therefore you won't likely get much help without posting some code I'm afraid.

Comment: @ade: i have not created the 2 appDelegate methods,we get it by default when we create a universal app.

Comment: what sdk are you using? when I create an empty application (used to be called window based I think) I only get one app delegate.

Comment: @ade:i am working on Xcode 4 ios sdk 4.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, Your question is really a confusing one. I think you are looking for something like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

 if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
      self.viewController = //Initialize the ViewController for iPhone environment 
 } 
 else {
      self.viewController =  //Initialize the ViewController for iPad environment
 }
 self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] 
                             initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
 [self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
 [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
 return YES;
}
```

If this is not the answer you are looking for then please update your question with some code.